# React button select change color

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a selectable button, so that it is easy, medium and difficult to choose when creating a task in the form

In this case, when he clicks on the easy, changing to the color is choosing, as for example:

easy: green
medium: yellow
high: red

my tsx component looks like this

```
interface IButtonProps extends ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  name: string;
}

const Priority: React.FC<IButtonProps> = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
  const [priority, setPriorite] = useState("");

  const { fieldName, defaultValue, error, registerField } = useField(name);

  useEffect(() => {
    registerField({
      name: fieldName,
      ref: inputRef.current,
      path: "value",
    });
  }, [fieldName, registerField]);

  return (
    <Container
      ref={inputRef}
      isActive={priority === "Low"}
      activeColor="red"
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
```

And my styled-component looks like this

```
interface RadioBoxProps {
  isActive: boolean;
  activeColor: string;
}

const colors: { [key: string]: any } = {
  red: "red",
  green: "green",
  blue: "blue",
};

export const Container = styled.button<RadioBoxProps>`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  height: 2.5rem;
  border: 2px solid;

  font: 1rem Poppins;
  background: transparent;

  border-radius: 0.25rem;

  transition: border-color 0.2s;

  background: ${(props) =>
    props.isActive ? colors[props.activeColor] : "transparent"};
`;
```

I would like to know the bug that when I select it, it doesn't have the color assigned to it to be sent to the backend

Comment: Doesn't seem as though anything ever calls `setPriorite` to update the `priority` state, so the `isActive` prop value is always `false` and the button is never "activated". It is rather unclear what `Container` component is supposed to be (*button? radio option? other?*) and what you want the behavior to be. What is "the easy"? The colors mentioned in your description don't match what you've coded. Can you try cleaning up your question to help make your issue and desired behavior a lot clearer and easier to understand?

Comment: Yes, the container is a button to simulate a checkbox.